# Rest template exchange not accept ParameterizedTypeReference

Tags: spring, rest

Oops guys! Beauty? I'm trying to get a byte list[] in my Rest template's response, but my exchange isn't accepting the new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<byte[]>>() {} , could someone help me?

```
    ResponseEntity<List<byte[]>> response = null;
        try {
            response = restTemplate.exchange(parametros.get("SERVICE_HUB2_BASE_URL") + "/fw/v1/pdf/kms/assinaturas", 
                    HttpMethod.POST, entity, new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<byte[]>>() {});
        } catch (HttpServerErrorException e) { 
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new ClientException(e.getStatusCode().value(), e.getStatusText());
        } catch (HttpClientErrorException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new ClientException(e.getStatusCode().value(), e.getStatusText());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

[image]

Comment: [`exchange`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#exchange-org.springframework.http.RequestEntity-java.lang.Class-) has **eight(!)** overloads, please be more precise/use the best suited method! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Hi As per the mouse hower it's pointing to different method.

Please check import statement for rest template.

both ways should be fine .

```
ResponseEntity<Collection<byte[]>> responseEntityOne = restTemplate.exchange(formattedUrl, HttpMethod.POST, entity,
                new ParameterizedTypeReference<Collection<byte[]>>(){});

ResponseEntity<List<byte[]>> responseEntityOne1 = restTemplate.exchange(formattedUrl, HttpMethod.POST, entity,
                new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<byte[]>>(){});
```